# can we use __libc_stack_end to determine stack end on linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction, stack

can we use __libc_stack_end to determine stack end conditon on Linux stack navigation algorithm? when i use it, i get undeclared identifier like compilation errors.

as it is in the gcc library, i doubt how can we use it.. and what is for other compilers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an identifier starting with two underscores, it is definitely implementation specific.

So if you want your code to work with other implementations, don't use it.

My debugger says that it does not know about it (Debian/Sid).

Comment: AFAICS there's not even any kind of promise it'll still be there or have the same meaning in future versions of Glibc.  Ordinary applications should certainly keep well clear of it.